# How do the histogram and number of colors in the texture affect a displacement map?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, displacement

I've been working on a displacement map texture of the Moon taken from NASA data. When the step of resizing the original image down to 65536 x 32768 was done, many new shades of gray were added. As a result, tiles of that image that are 8192 px on a side are on average 5 times the file size of tiles made from the original image, even though those are 11,520 px on a side. The full resized image is 1.5 GB.

Concerned about that overhead, I resized the image again using nearest-neighbor interpolation so the resulting image would have the same colors as the original. It's hard to properly test that it does as I can't open the full original image, but combining two tiles with especially low and high points into one image, the count there is 153 shades of gray**, while the resized image with NN interpolation has 157.

The NN image is only 169 MB, much more manageable. Also, the image is a 16-bit PNG. The original is a 16-bit TIFF so I figured I should stick to that. But it could be reduced to an 8-bit PNG if the color range was stretched out. Then it would be much smaller again.

However, I wonder about using that reduced range of gray tones in a displacement map. Will the resulting geometry be jagged? Is it easy enough to smooth it out, so no worries?

Here are histograms of the NN resize (top) and the regular resize (bottom)

[image]

And a histogram and colorcube analysis of one of the highest contrast tiles (later I combined two and did that again, but didn't take a screenshot)

[image]

By the way, the tiles are available [here](https://www.moonwards.com/project.html#assets), though you might want to wait a couple of days, because I'll replace the 8192 ones with these smaller ones, depending on the answers here.

---

<sub>**What can you do, it's hard to be precise using a laser altimeter from a probe orbiting hundreds of km above the surface and moving at over 1 km/s.</sub>

Comment: "*Will the resulting geometry be jagged?*" Hard to tell, it *is* possible, but I believe you would need a very (impractically) high resolution mesh and/or a very large elevation interval for it to become noticeable. Either way I believe it'd be easy to smooth out, at the expense of accuracy.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos what you'd lose in accuracy in one sense you'd gain in another sense - the Moon is most definitely not jagged. Later overlays added on could correct any resulting inaccuracy, as a long-term goal.

Comment: If hosting is no issue, then IMO the more options the merrier.  I have blown some downloads on NASA dems and often end up using GDAL to reduce down to a LOD that is more than good enough for my dicking around without grinding blender to a stop, or (with our ISP robbers in Oz) blowing my data limit.

Comment: @batFINGER GDAL, huh? I'd not heard of that so i looked it up. For my purposes, i think i don't need it, which is good because i don't know coding and it looks like it also has a bit of a learning curve... I suppose i can offer both packages of tiles. My HS supposedly offers unlimited bandwidth.

Comment: Actually, now that i've done the math, an option that makes a ton of sense is offering the original as a zipped folder of tiles measuring 1024 px on a side. Which is so considerate of NASA, to set it up that way. I guess GIS packages like powers of 2 too.